# Visual Studio: find and replace ALL CAPS with Title Case

Tags: visual-studio, regex, visual-studio-2008, replace

Consider the need to replace window titles that are currently in all caps i.e. "ADD PRESCRIPTION", "ADD PATIENT", to the form "Add Prescription" and "Add Patient".

I am using the Visual Studio search dialog to find all of the strings that are all caps using the regex `"([A-Z]|[ ])*"`. That works great.

Is it possible to find and replace in Visual Studio with a regex on both the find **and** replace?

I can't seem to find anything that says that it is, so if it's not are there any tools that would let me replace it.

Comment: thanks for the title edit, I didn't know what to call that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know a Visual Studio way but to roll out your own C# program which handles the replace part explicitly.

But in [Vim](http://www.vim.org), you can use `:%s/\([A-Z]\)\([A-Z][A-Z]*\)/\1\L\2/g` command. The `\L` is used to change the matching group `\2` (a.k.a back reference) to lower case.

Before:

```
"HELLO WORLD" 
This is just a test.
SO stands for StackOverflow.
```

After:

```
"Hello World"
This is just a test.
So stands for StackOverflow.
```

Comment: I know how to write the regex to do it in on input text also I'm also curious if there is a way to do it in VS.

Comment: Totally forgot to upvote you because this is a good answer, but not The Answer